# How to use ternary operator in echo statement in php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, ternary

here i have a simple code which is response using ajax . in action page i have select box(for qty)(9 options)(size="1") . my code checks in database product qty so i want to display the qty(from database) "selected" . how can i use ternary operator
Here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['getcart'])){

    $cart_item_query = "SELECT * FROM cart";
    $cart_item_run = mysqli_query($conn,$cart_item_query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($cart_item_run)>0){
        $grand_total=0;
        while($cart_row=mysqli_fetch_array($cart_item_run)){
            $pro_id = $cart_row['product_id'];
            $pro_qty = $cart_row['qty'];
            $product_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id'";
            $product_run = mysqli_query($conn, $product_query);
            $product_row = mysqli_fetch_array($product_run);
            $pro_name = $product_row['product_name'];
            $pro_image = $product_row['product_image'];
            $pro_sell_price = $product_row['sell_price'];
            $total = $pro_sell_price*$pro_qty;
            $grand_total =$grand_total+ $total;





            echo "<div class='row'>

                                    <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'><img src='img/$pro_image' alt='' width='50px'></div>
                                    <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'><p>$pro_name</p><a href=''><p><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> Remove</p></a></div>
                                    <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'><select class='change_qty' size='1' style='width:50px;'>
                                     <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='1' ".$pro_qty==1?'selected':''.">1</option>
                                    <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='2' ".$pro_qty==2?'selected':''.">2</option>
                                    <option class='qty'  data-pro='$pro_id' value='3' ".$pro_qty==3?'selected':''.">3</option>
                                    <option class='qty'  data-pro='$pro_id' value='4' ".$pro_qty==4?'selected':''.">4</option>
                                    <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='5' ".$pro_qty==5?'selected':''.">5</option>
                                    <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='6' ".$pro_qty==6?'selected':''.">6</option>
                                    <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='7' ".$pro_qty==7?'selected':''.">7</option>
                                    <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='8' ".$pro_qty==8?'selected':''.">8</option>
                                    <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='9' ".$pro_qty==9?'selected':''.">9</option>

                                        </select></div>

                                    <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'><input data-pro='$pro_id' id = 'price- $pro_id' type='text' value='$pro_sell_price' disabled class='form-control dis-input price' ></div>

                                    <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'><input id = 'total-$pro_id' data-pro='$pro_id' type='text' value='$total' disabled class='form-control dis-input total' ></div>

                                </div>

                                <hr>
                                ";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I dont know how to write correct code for this. i want to print "selected" there if my $pro_qty variable == 1.
please help

Comment: You don't write a ternary directly into the string

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Sir,then how can i solve this?

Comment: Why did your variable switch from $qty to $pro_qty? What does `$pro_qty` actually equal? Try to echo it before that div

Comment: no. i am fetching qty  from database and saving it in $pro_qty variable

Comment: I still need to know what `$pro_qty` equals.

Comment: its in a while loop so for every product it has different qty .. in my case i have 4 products and qtys are 7,3,1,1 serially

Comment: Is that what it actually echo's?

Comment: i have updated post again here is more code please check.....outside div if i try to echo "$pro_qty";   onpage it shows 7311 (because of while loop)

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by it's "not working"

Comment: my code is correct? is there any syntax error?

Comment: Correct, there are no syntax errors that I see

Comment: when i run it it breaks my page structure. without turnery it shows ok.

Comment: I normally don't make a very large echo statement like you did unless I am using Heredocs, I would try to echo each line of HTML seperately. Or switch out of PHP, echo it all with plain HTML and fill in the variables with PHP

Comment: but in this case what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know, I'm rewriting your code now to see if I can find an issue.

Comment: or maybe those double quotes ("") creating bug. because this echo is going back to ajax  as responseText .

Comment: You are missing 2 closing braces for the html in your last 2 inputs after the select statement. [This is how I would have written the code](https://pastebin.com/EC0C2d8N)

Comment: where am i missing closing braces i cant find.

Comment: ohh those slashes (/)??

Comment: Actually it looks like you have it there in your code, not sure what happened when I copied it

Comment: i read your code . thats excellent. but i have to wrap it in a div for the ajax request. so echo inside echo i think not acceptable. my action page is different and display page is different . so i am passing variable through ajax to the action page . action page process my data... ( wrapped in echo) and send response to js and from there i am sending to display it on another   page... all this  can i achieve  by your code?

Comment: The problem is in your parent then, not the code you supplied here.

Comment: But without turnery it shows correct but after adding turnery it creates problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't write ternaries directly into the string, you need to insert it into the string sort of like a variable, like this:

```
echo "<option value='1' ".$qty == 1? 'selected' : ''." >1</option> ";
```

Notice how I broke the string with before the ternary with `"`, added a period to concatenate the ternary, ending with another period at the end of the ternary, and started the string again with another `"`.

You can find more detail about this at the PHP manual: [String Operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

---

### Alternatives

## Seperate ternary from string

I usually use curly braces to concatenate strings into other strings, if your echo statement is surrounded by double quotes (**not** single quotes), you can use this method

I would have written this with the ternary seperate from the actual string, like this:

```
$selected = $qty == 1? 'selected' : '';
echo "<option value='1' {$selected}>1</option>";
```

OR you could drop the curly brackets, but I find this less readable, and harder to tell where variables are. The string also must be wrapped in double quotes.

```
$selected = $qty == 1? 'selected' : '';
echo "<option value='1' $selected>1</option>";
```

## Using Commas

You can also do string separation by commas:

```
$selected = $qty == 1? 'selected' : '';
echo "<option value='1'", $selected, ">1</option>";
```

Alternatively,

```
echo "<option value='1'", $qty == 1? 'selected' : '', ">1</option>";
```

Comment: You can also use `,` if you like.

Comment: Where could that be used @Don'tPanic? I've never seen a markup like that

Comment: `echo` can echo multiple expressions separated by commas.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What is it doing?

Comment: @kohali you'll have to show me more code to understand, but the same principal applies.

Comment: echo "<div class='row'>

         <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'><img src='img/$pro_image' alt='' width='50px'></div>
         <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3'><p>$pro_name</p><a href=''><p><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> Remove</p></a></div>
         <div class='col-md-2 col-xs-2'><select class='change_qty' size='1' style='width:50px;'>
                      <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='1' ".$pro_qty==1?'selected':''.">1</option>
                     <option class='qty' data-pro='$pro_id' value='2' ".$pro_qty==2?'selected':''.">2</option>

Comment: and so on till 9 options

Comment: @kohali Update your main post please with properly formatted code

Comment: Yeah, that's right. echo can take any number of expressions that will evaluate to strings, and it just outputs them one after another. It isn't really concatenation, but same effect, basically.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That's really neat I've never seen that markup before

Comment: Yeah! There are a couple of Q&As here about performance of one v. the other. Apparently echo w/comma is a little quicker, but most people seem to agree it's a microoptimization in most cases.

Comment: What is wrong with this code. ($j == $n) ? echo('#') : echo(' ');